# разбить неограниченный цикл из mysql постранично

Tags: php, циклы

Имею простой цикл вайл, в него может попасть очень много записей, они могут массово добавляться, могут массово удаляться.

Подскажите как разбить это.

Comment: Удаление, добавление происходит асинхронно? Подробно опишите задачу

Comment: вывод списка рефералов

Comment: Вы не верно поняли. Есть к примеру 10000 записей без постраничной разбивкой. Добавляются и удаляются записи отдельно? Или на той же странице путем асинхронного запроса?

Comment: ну если это рефералы. конечно отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя из слова "постранично" в заголовке, предпологаю, что это вопрос про пагинацию.

В простейшем случае, с использованием MySql, это можно сделать так:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id FROM some_table;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Второй запрос вернет Вам количество найденных записей, сохраняете это значение в приложении (`$elements`). 
Далее, делите это значение на количество элементов, которое Вы хотите видеть на одной странице (`$elementsPerPage`), получаете количество страниц.

```
$pagesCount = $element/$elementsPerPage; // не забудьте округлить значение
```

Вам каким-то образом нужно принимать номер запрошенной страницы для вывода, простейший способ - ожидать и передавать ее в `$_GET['page']`.
Если номер страницы явно не указан, считаем, что запрос идет на просмотр первой страницы.
Т.е.

`/referals - запрос на просмотр 1ой стр
/referals?page=1 - запрос на просмотр первой страницы
/referals?page=12 - запрос на просмотр 12ой страницы`.

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
if (!$page) {
    $page = 1;
}
```

Далее Вам необходимо ограничить выборку записей, которую будете посылать в цикл `while`.

```
$offset = ($page-1) * $elementsPerPage;
if (!$offset) {
    $limit = "LIMIT {$elementsPerPage}";
} else {
    $limit = "LIMIT {$offset}, {$elementsPerPage}";
}
```

Выражение `$limit` нужно добавить к вашему SELECT запросу, который получает данные, чтобы потом передать их в цикл.
Теперь в цикл будет передаваться только определенное кол-во записей (которое будет <= `$elementsPerPage`). Для обработки следующей порции, необходимо запросить следующую страницу.
Конечно, стоит не забыть отрисовать где-то на странице ссылки для навигации между страницами (каждая ссылка должна передавать в `$_GET['page']` номер страницы, на которую ссылается).

**UPD. Навигация.**

Функция, которая "в лоб" создает сверстанный блок с навигацией для этого кейса. Привожу ее, чтобы Вы ознакомились с идеей, но надеюсь, что Вы не будете ее использовать AS IS, а просто посмотрите, поймете идею и внедрите этот функционал в свой проект, подходящим образом, возложив ответственность на соответствующий компонент системы.

```
/**
*@param int $pagesCount Всего страниц
*@param int $currentPage Номер текущей страницы
*@param int $navParam Сколько страницы показывать до и после текущей
*/
function buildPageNavigation($pagesCount, $currentPage = 1, $navParam = 3) {
    $html = '<span>';
    $html .= '<a href="/referals?page=1"> 1 </a>';
    $before = $currentPage - $navParam;
    if ($currentPage > 1) {
        if ($before <= 2) {
            $start = 2;
        } else {
            $start = $before;
            $html .= ' ... ';
        }
        for ($i = $start; $i <= $currentPage; $i++) {
            $html .= '<a href="/referals?page=' . $i .'"> ' . $i .' </a>';
        }
    }
    $after = $currentPage + $navParam;
    if ($after >= $pagesCount) {
        $end = $pagesCount;
    } else {
        $end = $after;
    }
    for ($i = $currentPage; $i <= $end; $i++) {
        $html .= '<a href="/referals?page=' . $i .'"> ' . $i .' </a>';
    }
    if ($after < ($pagesCount - 1)) {
        $html .= ' ... ';
        $html .= '<a href="/referals?page=' . $pagesCount .'"> ' . $pagesCount .' </a>';
    } elseif ($after <= $pagesCount) {
        $html .= '<a href="/referals?page=' . $pagesCount .'"> ' . $pagesCount .' </a>';
    }
    $html .= '</span>';
    return $html;
}
```

Функция вернет строку, содержащую html-разметку меню-навигации.
Теперь вывести меню можно так `echo buildPageNavigation($pagesCount, $currentPage);` .

Comment: а как округлить число. подскажите.

Comment: Был бы очень благодарен, если бы ещё и рассказали как кнопочек автоматическое количество тоже постранично выводить, то есть кнопки со стрелками навигации по ним типа: `<< < 3 4 5 6 7 8 > >>`. А пока всё получилось, правда замучился сопоставлять с моим кодом =), но все работает. Еще сделал нумерацию строк в цикле $i = $offset + 1; $i++; )) С кнопками пока не знаю как.

Comment: необходимо что-бы была кнопка и к первой странице. и к последней, и на какой странице мы сейчас находимся. ну и можно 3 предидущих страницы показать и 3 последующих. вот так бы было идеально

Comment: дополню завтра ответ, расскажу как это можно сделать

Comment: а пока по простятски сделал. сделал кнопку на какой страничке сейчас находимся. и сделал кнопки -1 и +1 =)

Comment: Спасибо большое за дополнение, конечно буду ковыряться и сам думать. сначала поставлю это, дальше химичить буду, потом сам сделаю)